# CORS Error while fetching data from Wiki Js (GraphQL)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, wiki

I'm getting CORS error while fetching data from wiki js graphql endpoint in my react app. I'm using REACT SSR.

here is what I'm doing

`App.js`

```
const client = new ApolloClient({
  uri: 'https://example-wiki.herokuapp.com/graphql',
  cache: new InMemoryCache(),
  headers: {
    Authorization:
      'Bearer exampleToken1234abc',
  },
});
```

`api.js`

```
import { useQuery, gql } from '@apollo/client';

const ALL_PAGES_QUERY = gql`
  query PageQuery {
    pages {
      list {
        id
        title
        tags
      }
    }
  }
`;

export const getAllPages = () => {
  const { loading, error, data } = useQuery(ALL_PAGES_QUERY);

  return {
    loading,
    error,
    data,
  };
};
```

`error`

`Access to fetch at 'https://example-wiki.herokuapp.com/graphql' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. If an opaque response serves your needs, set the request's mode to 'no-cors' to fetch the resource with CORS disabled.`

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uFCUM.png)
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HmCbP.png)

I've already tried this solution
https://github.com/requarks/wiki/discussions/3056

provided by one of the maintainer of Wiki Js. but its not working at all

Comment: When you're saying you "tried this solution", I assume you are talking about reversing the commits from `c57c9d9`? Because since that was added, Wiki.js does not support CORS requests until v3.0 comes out.